# Customize Spring's JdbcBatchItemWriter to use different SQL for every record

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement where I will receive a flat file from a vendor and I need to read the records and insert/update/delete them in my DB table. I get the action flag from vendor indicating whether I need to insert/update/delete that particular record. The flat file will contain huge records and I do not want to do manual steps like checking the action flag for every record [by overriding write() method of ItemWriter and looping the items list in chunk] and construct sql manually and use JDBCTemplate to do the DB operation for every record.

Can I achieve this using JdbcBatchItemWriter? Is there a way to set the sql for every record in the chunk so that Spring Batch will do a batch update? How does the ItemPreparedStatementSetter can be invoked in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Since your choice is at the record level, take a look at the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html).  That `ItemWriter` implementation takes a `Classifier` implementation that it uses to determine which `ItemWriter` to use.  From there, you can configure one `ItemWriter` that does inserts, one for updates, and one for deletes.  Each record will be funneled through to the correct instance and assuming your delegates are `JdbcBatchItemWriter`s, you'll get the same batching you normally do (one batch for inserts, one for updates, and one for deletes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike!! I am wondering how the skip policy will work in that case. I am using AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy and I hope that will still work the same way when using ClassifierCompositeItemWriter since I have to send back a file to the vendor with all data about failed records [no matter what, my batch implementation should never fail and should read and update all records in the incoming flat file].

Comment: It shouldn't have an impact.  When an exception is thrown in the `ItemWriter`, the entire chunk is rolled back and retried item by item so we can identify which item to skip.